# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 in flutter upgrade

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I upgrade my flutter but after that I can't run my code and see the result
here is my code. I also wanted to use audio player package but it didn't work for me.
changing the version of SDK also didn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child:TextButton
              (onPressed: (){


              },
             child:Text('Click Me')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the error I can't solve

```
Running "flutter pub get" in tessssssssssssssst...
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

     Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0-alpha05' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

     Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0-alpha05' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{projectname}/android/app/build.gradle` and find `compileSdkVersion` and change it to `32`

Comment: It didn't work and actually in update  we should write it in local.properties @Hardikmehta

Comment: you can write directly  compileSdkVersion 32 like that

Comment: you mean in local.properties ?
it is like this for me :
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=32
flutter.compileSdkVersion=32
@hardikmehta

Comment: you can change in local.properties as it taking from that :  you are good to go

Comment: It didn't work again

Comment: Then directly write in build.gradle file instead of  compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion, just write   compileSdkVersion 32

Comment: I did it 
Same error

Comment: try clean and build again

Comment: you can ignore targetSdkVersion or comment out that

Comment: Thank you 
It finally workssssss :)
@hardikmehta

Answer (score 0):

In your

> android/app/build.gradle

Change **compileSdkVersion** to 32

Comment: Didn't work @maqsood

Comment: after changing to 32, you got same error or a different one.

Comment: no same error ....
compileSdkVersion to 32 is true but in new version we have to add flutter.compileSdkVersion